# Custom framework Not working ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I had created an custom framework and added to Embedded binaries and linked frameworks with Xcode but i'm still getting the below errors.Please let me kknow how to overcome the below issue

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Accountsession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in InputController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PXHardwareId", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DownloadViewController.o

Comment: You have framework version to x-code version issue.

Comment: Can you explain or give some more information about the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `$(inherited)` added into your Other Linker Flags.

Go to *Xcode > Target Settings > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags* > Add entry for `$(inherited)`

Also check your project *Architectures* and *Valid Architectures* settings for all the build phases.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i had already added but i'm still facing same error

Comment: Can you please check, if there are any round robin import statements. For example: ClassA.h having `import "ClassB.h"` and in ClassB.h its having `import "ClassA.h"`. Especially in your classes ViewController.h, InputController.h, DownloadViewController.h.